# real time application in C# MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, websocket, asp.net-ajax, signalr

My application required to show real time data. 
Here is brief idea. 
User will run Import (Some add/edit/delete operation) in database. And I want to show real time Log of Import on UI.

Can you please suggest any good examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best if you start here: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr

Then based on your scenario you can proceed by this (sending updates from back-end): http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-signalr

You could use the idea from the example by invoking the events in your data access layer or similar.

Or you could search for something more suitable for your needs.